# Modifying margins and header of a template

Tags: margins, templates

I am using [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/assignment-template/hwddqynqfrhn) for a document. I would like to modify the lower margin, because it is too small as it is.

I have tried substituting `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` with `\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}` but the document looks the same.

I would also like to remove the title of the section that gets added to the header. I have tried removing different packages in `settings.tex` but have not managed to get rid of it and still don't know which particular setting causes it.

Comment: 25mm is not precisely 1in, but they definitely look the same.  Perhaps your default paper size is also A4.  `\let\sectionmark\@gobble` should remove it, but the definition will get renewed with `\pagestyle`.

Answer (score 1):

For example use for `settings.tex`

```
%%file settings.tex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=25mm, right=25mm, left =25mm, bottom=40mm]{geometry} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{accents}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setlength{\headheight}{42pt} % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    
\newenvironment{solution}
  {\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
  \begin{proof}[Solution]}
  {\end{proof}}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}

\newcommand{\ubar}[1]{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}
```

to expand the bottom space.

The heading  are controlled by

```
\lhead{Mathy McMathface} 
\rhead{MATH101 Spring '19 \\ Mathical Mathy-Maths \\ Assignment 1} 
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

in `main.tex`